# Plotting currents data on a map : Too many value to unpack error

Tags: python, matplotlib

So here is my code :

```
from netCDF4 import *
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nc=Dataset('datasets/essai.nc')

time_var = nc.variables[str('forecast_time0')]
wave_var = nc.variables['DIST_GDS0_SFC']
lat = nc.variables['g0_lat_1'][:]
lon = nc.variables['g0_lon_2'][:]
uin = nc.variables['UOGRD_GDS0_DBSL'][:]
vin = nc.variables['VOGRD_GDS0_DBSL'][:]
plt.quiver(lon[::5], lat[::5], uin[::5], vin[::5], scale=200)
```

And here is the error I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nctry.py", line 37, in <module>
    plt.quiver(lon[::5], lat[::5], uin[::5], vin[::5], scale=200)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2877, in quive
r
    ret = ax.quiver(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 6627, in quiver
    q = mquiver.Quiver(self, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\quiver.py", line 394, in __init
__
    X, Y, U, V, C = _parse_args(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\quiver.py", line 356, in _parse
_args
    nr, nc = U.shape
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I think the problem comes from the UOGRD and VOGRD which has many values but don't know how manipulate it?

Here is how uogrd looks like : [image: UOGRD]

the forecast_time up as far as a number of 4.

Ok so I used the np.array and shape functions, here is what i've got :

> C:\Python27>python nctry.py 
>   (321,) //lat 
>   (720,) //lon
>   (4, 321, 720) //uogrd 
>   (4, 321, 720) //vogrd

Then I tried this code :

[image: code]

but it only shows one arrow. Can you tell me why?

So now I have some modelling which looks like this : 
[image: currents modelized]

But this image doesn't change, for [0, :, :], 1, 2 or 3.. What's wrong? 
Furthermore, all the arrows are going to the same direction, not really true when we're talking about currents' ocean. I use the deg2rad function.
Finally, I can't imagine the coastlines, is that normal? 
Thank you

Comment: Perhaps display some of what `U0GRID` looks like. I am having trouble installing the netCDF4 package, so I can't look at the dataset myself. Perhaps you could convert the `lat`, `lon`, etc. lists to `np.array`s then print out `.shape` of each array so we can see the dimensionality

Comment: @Bill post is updated

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `UOGRD` (and probably `VOGRD` too) contains too many dimensions. You need to reduce the number of dimensions by slicing it. However, given the current information, I cannot instruct you which dimension to remove.

However, you should convert the `lat`, `lon`, `UOGRD` and `VOGRD` to `np.array` using the command and print out each array's shape

```
UOGRD = np.array(UOGRD)
print UOGRD.shape
```

Do this for all 4 of your arrays. This will print out tuples `(d1_length, d2_length, ..., dn_length)`.

If we know the dimensionality of `lat=N` and `lon=M`, we should hope that the dimensions of `UOGRD` will be something like `(N, M, x, y, z)` and we can slice out the dimensions we don't need.

**EDIT:**

From the shape functions  in your, it shows us that `uin` and `vin` are both 3 dimensional. And you can see that `len(lat) = 321`, `len(lon) = 720` and both `uin` and `vin` have dimensions `(x, 321, 720)`. That means we want to plot the last two dimensions of `uin` and `vin`. Therefore, try this

```
uin = nc.variables['UOGRD_GDSO_DBSL']
uin = np.array(uin)
uin = uin[0, :, :]
vin = nc.variables['vOGRD_GDSO_DBSL']
vin = np.array(vin)
vin = vin[0, :, :]
```

Do not do `uin = uin.shape` as that will set `uin = (4, 321, 720)` instead of your data. The only thing is, we have to figure out is which index we should put in the slicing. Try `[0,:,:]` then `[1,:,:]` ... `[3,:,:]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Bill, post is updated once again if it doesn't matter you to help me again

Comment: I didn't see what's the use of the shape function, so I removed it in my code but still the same error : to many value to unpack (and btw I sliced the wrong data, I changed with [:0])

Comment: Thanks for your help, the other question is removed, my post is updated

Comment: Bill, I create a new post because of the mess I created on this one with all the edits.